# Openinviter not fetching facebook contacts from 1 Oct 2011?

Tags: php

I have implemented Openinviter,previously it was working fine but from 1st October 2011 it stops fetching contacts from facebook.can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps:

http://openinviter.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=134

Comment: Thanks...but i am not sure that is it a nameserver problem of facebook...i haven't got my answer yet..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quite a few of plugins do not work since sometime (earlier than Oct 1 for me though). You can use http://www.plaxo.com/api/widget instead, or implement your own using Oauth. Oauth type solutions are better since you do not ask for people's credentials, which is a very dubious practice in fact.